# in d3js how can I filter data by clicking on stack bar

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js

I'm trying to filter data by clicking on certain rect bar in a stacked bar. This stack bar is a two dimention graph, the horizontal index is years, and the vertical index different product revenues, I want to filter by certain product in certain year. means when I click on a rect bar of the whole graph, the data should get filtered by certain year and certain product.

my code is :

```
metrics.on("click", function(d,i,j){
         d3.select(this)
         .style("fill","lightcoral")
         .style("stroke","red");
         fdata =rawdata.filter(function(d){return (d[xvalue]==_seriesA[i])&&(d[yvalue]==_seriesB[j])});
    });
```

but the weird thing is the value of j is always undefined, although if I attach a title to it :

```
metrics.append("title").text(
            function(d,i,j) {
                return i + ' - '+j ;
            });
```

the value of j will get printed correctly, is there anything special about the 'on' click function? why I cannot get the value of j? any help will be appreciated....this is triving me crazy for the whole night...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), the second argument to `.on()` is a function that takes two arguments, not three. Similarly, it shouldn't work in your second example either.

I think you're getting confused about the distinction between the data and how it is rendered. The `.on()` function will get you the data. The scales you have created somewhere in your code take that data and map it to `x` and `y` coordinates in your graph (or you use the data directly without scales). In the `.on()` function, you use the data in exactly the same way you used it when you created the graph to start with. That is, the data item (`d` in your code) contains the data for the specific position that you're highlighting.

Comment: thanks! you are right, I need to add j as one of the value of d. Another workaround is use 'this.parentElement', for stack bars it contains the information of it's layer.